Mat Accordion multi=false with 2 panels A and B. How to make A open when keyup.ENTER event occurs in B?
This should be simple but I believe its being complicated by the fact that the Panel B contains an ACE editor control.
I'm capturing the (keyup.ENTER) event in the Ace editor control as well as in its parent Panel B expansion-panel container in order to (1) Collapse the Panel B that contains the ACE editor, and (2) open/expand the Panel A that contains the preview that is built from the ACE editor's html content.
Maybe I'm overthinking this but although I can log out the keyup.ENTER event from the ACE editor as well as the keyup.ENTER event from its parent mat-expansion-panel, I'm unable to get the panel B to close and panel A to open as a result of this event.
My console.log shows that the value of the expanded variables are changing, but the expansion panels do not seem to want to cooperate.
Here is the template code:
<mat-accordion multi="false">
    <!--PANEL A-->
      <mat-expansion-panel 
        *ngIf="dragDropMode"
        #panelA
        class="canvas-panel" 
        [expanded]="dragDropMode || editorPanelExpanded"
        (opened)="setEditorPanel(true)"
      >
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>Panel A</mat-panel-title>
        <mat-panel-description></mat-panel-description>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
        <mat-card>
          <mat-accordion [multi]="multiAccordion">
            Panel A
          </mat-accordion>
        </mat-card>
      </ng-template>
    </mat-expansion-panel>

    <!-- PANEL B -->
    <mat-expansion-panel
      *ngIf="ifDeveloper && (developerMode$ | async)"
      #panelB
      class="model-panel"
      (opened)="setEditorPanel(false, 'Panel B Opened')"
      (keyup.ENTER)="setEditorPanel(true, 'ACE PARENT keyup.ENTER')"
    >
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>Panel B</mat-panel-title>
        <mat-panel-description></mat-panel-description>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
        <div
          ace-editor
          *ngIf="panelB.expanded"
          [text]="text$ | async"
          [options]="aceEditorOptions"
          [autoUpdateContent]="true"
          (textChanged)="updateModelFromEditor($event)"
          class="ace-editor-container"
          (keyup.ENTER)="setEditorPanel(true, 'ACE keyup.ENTER')"
        ></div>
      </ng-template>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>

And here is the typescript class code:
 editorPanelExpanded = true;

 setEditorPanel(value: boolean, from = '') {
   this.editorPanelExpanded = value;
   console.log(`setEditorPanelCalled from ${from} with value: ${value}`);
 }

At launch of the app, the Panel A is open. I then click on Panel B to auto expand it, which automatically causes Panel A to close. Then I select some text inside the ACE editor in Panel B and click ENTER. At that point I get the console.log as expected showing the variables changed, but Panel B remains open and Panel A remains closed. I must be violating some rule of the mat-accordion in this instance but I can't seem to figure what. Can someone suggest an alternate approach perhaps or tell me where I'm going wrong with my current approach?
Edit: I forgot to add perhaps important detail. I'm using onPush change detection. I'm about to insert a detectChanges() into my script to test the results.
Yea, CD had no impact on the behavior. Panel A still remains closed. I can get panel B to close on the event trigger, but still Panel A remains closed, despite logs that show its [expanded] variable is true while its collapsed.
I've spent hours testing back and forth on this and I'm just out of ideas to try.

I finally got this to work. They key was accessing the .open() method of the expansion-panel. In order to access that, I had to set up a viewChild reference to it.
In the class:
@ViewChild('editor') editor: MatExpansionPanel;
Panel A has the viewChild #editor reference:
<mat-expansion-panel #editor ...>
Panel B has the keyup.Enter event handler that calls the method:
<mat-expansion-panel (keyup.ENTER)="openEditor()"
The openEditor() method does the work:
openEditor() { this.editor.open(); }
